# SELinux not allowing read files on ~/.cert

Tags: fedora, openvpn, selinux

I'm new to Fedora 23 and SELinux. I use an OpenVPN client through NetworkManager. I stored all the files I needed OpenVPN to access (certificate, CA and private key) inside `~/.cert` and ran `updatecon -R -v ~/.cert`. However, I'm still getting AVC errors from SELinux, who won't let OpenVPN access such files. This the relevant portion of the output of `grep AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log | less`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1457179403.296:364): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2608 comm="nm-openvpn-serv" path="/home/ggoncalves/.cert/ggoncalves.key" dev="dm-2" ino=2888752 scontext=system_u:system_r:NetworkManager_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c50,c545 tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1457179403.296:365): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2608 comm="nm-openvpn-serv" path="/home/ggoncalves/.cert/ggoncalves.key" dev="dm-2" ino=2888752 scontext=system_u:system_r:NetworkManager_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c50,c545 tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1457179403.330:366): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2611 comm="openvpn" name="lastline-ca.crt" dev="dm-2" ino=2888749 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c50,c545 tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1457179403.332:367): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2611 comm="openvpn" name="ggoncalves.crt" dev="dm-2" ino=2888751 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c50,c545 tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1457179403.332:368): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2611 comm="openvpn" name="ggoncalves.key" dev="dm-2" ino=2888752 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c50,c545 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Since I've only been using SELinux for a few days, I have no clue where to start looking for this. Any hints?

**Edit:** It seems to me that the problem is in the `svirt_sandbox_file_t` label. I believe those files should be labelled `home_cert_t`.

**Edit 2:** In fact, my whole home directory has been labeled `svirt_sandbox_file_t` for some reason. Is this a feature or a bug of Docker policies?

### Update

Alright, this took a while. Let me further describe the issue, in case someone ends up going through the same. Turns out the `svirt_sandbox_file_t` had been attributed by Docker when I mounted my home directory as a volume with the `:Z` flag (as described [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/)). Docker then recursively applied that label to my entire home dir, and somehow neither reconfiguring the FS labels nor applying `restorecon` worked.

To restore my home to the original permissions, I `rsync`'d it to a temporary folder, deleted everything in it and `rsync`'d back. Not the brightest idea, but it worked.

Comment: Don't mount your home directory as a Docker volume, only chosen subdirectories of the home directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target context type of the files is still wrong:

```
svirt_sandbox_file_t
```

The files in `~/.cert` should be labeled as `home_cert_t`. Give it a try once more with

```
restorecon -Rf ~/.cert
```

or try to force the type:

```
chcon -t home_cert_t ~/.cert/*
```

It might be possible that there is some bug in selinux-policy or docker selinux policy that causes wrong default labeling.

Comment: Nope, still restoring to `svirt_sandbox_file_t`. I believe this has happened when I installed Docker...

Comment: Give it a try with `chcon`. I am not unfortunately didn't find such a bug, but I would blame `docker`.

Comment: `chcon` does fix it. Will this persist across reboots and FS changes?

Comment: Yes. It should persist over reboot, if you will not trigger relabel (or if Docker does not enforce it somehow).

Comment: Cool, I know what happened. I ran a command in my home directory inside a container with a `:Z` mount (as described [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/)), which basically ran `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t` over my entire home.

Comment: My question then is: isn't `restorecon` supposed to fix that exact problem?

Comment: Yes, it should. The policy contains default file/patch contexts. But they might somehow conflict with docker policy. You might try complete relabel of your system if you changed the whole home directory to something non-reasonable.

Comment: Do you mean `restorecon -Rf ~`? Because I did that, and nothing changed...

Comment: You can achieve complete relabel during reboot by `touch /.autorelabel` and then rebooting system.

Comment: Turns out that didn't work either, labels were untouched for my home. `audit2allow` didn't work either, and would throw some uninteligible error. I edited my question with the (rather poor) solution I came up with.